# Convert this to DateTime?

Tags: php

How can I convert the following date to DateTime format:

```
2013-02-21-12:25:13
```

The date is passed to us like this, with the - where a space should be between the date and time.

How can I convert this to a DateTime format? mySQL does it automatically but I want to do it with PHP.

We're looking for the following output:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d-H:i:s', '2013-02-21-12:25:13');
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And yes, this is [tested](http://viper-7.com/K1HsaX) and proven to work. It outputs:

```
2013-02-21 12:25:13
```

Comment: Perfect and clean, just what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` php function that will help you.

**Example**

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(YOUR_DATE_STRING));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
$old_date = '2013-02-21-12:25:13';
$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$old_date);
echo $new_date;
```

In one line it would be

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",'2013-02-21-12:25:13');
```

Comment: Yeah i tested it on your given link it outputs `1969-12-31 19:33:33`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $date = '2013-02-21-12:25:13';
  $new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date); 
  echo $new_date;
```

Comment: Well you should check your local again.... There's no way this will ever work. `date()` expects a timestamp, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_date = '2013-02-21-12:25:13';

$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($my_date));

echo $new_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = "2013-02-21-12:25:13";
$d = explode('-', $date);

$date=$d[0].'-'.$d[1].'-'.$d[2].' '.$d[3];
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
```

o/p:

```
2013-02-21 12:25:13
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2013-02-21-12:25:13';
$curdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d-H:i:s', $date);
echo $curdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This kill the point of using DateTime. Let DateTime parse the string with `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

non standard date format ? try to regexp your way out of that mess :

```
$string = "2013-02-21-12:25:13";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",
    strtotime(preg_replace("/(?:\d+-\d+-\d+)-{1}/","",$string))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = '2013-02-21-12:25:13';
echo substr_replace($date,' ',10,1);
```