# convert date dd/mm/yyyy format from a form to timestamp?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a form requiring date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format
and I've tried to convert it to a timestamp with `strtotime()` function

but I've seen it works only if you fill the form with date written like `dd-mm-yyyy`

how could i solve? I don't know abroad but here in Italy nobody writes dates like that `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: Why not create a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object instead, using [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert this to DateTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104397/convert-this-to-datetime)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Stop using `strotime()`, `date()`, `time()` etc. functions, start using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Perfect solution for all types of known input :

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $yourDMYinput);
echo $dt->getTimestamp(); # or $dt->format('U');
```

And why do you need timestamp for?

### Why explode, replace or even cut string??? Just use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

> **Q1:** Because its not supported below PHP 5.3.

There is v5.5 already out. I think answers should be for the latest code, not for code from the year 2006. Yes v5.2 was released in 2006 and v5.3 in 2009 ([see release dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)). If OP requests old code, find it on SO, and close this question with duplicate; don't answer it.

> **Q2:** Because I don't know DateTime.

Learn it.

> **Q3:** Because I can do more with `strotime()`, `date()`, `time()` etc.

Show me one thing that this functions can do, and DateTime cannot.

### "Deprecated" code examples :

```
$input = '12/09/2013'; # dd/mm/yyyy

$new = substr($input,6,4)."-".substr($input,3,2)."-".substr($input,0,2);
$new = strtotime($new);
echo "$new\n";

$m = explode('/', $input);
$new = mktime(0,0,0,$m[1],$m[0],$m[2]);
echo "$new\n";

$new = str_replace("/", "-", $input);
$new = strtotime($new);
echo "$new\n";

preg_match('~^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$~', $input, $m);
$new = strtotime("$m[3]-$m[2]-$m[1]");
echo "$new\n";

$m = sscanf($input, '%d/%d/%d');
$new = strtotime("$m[2]-$m[1]-$m[0]");
echo "$new\n";
```

*If you have another example of deprecated code, edit this answer and add it ;)*

Comment: I'm down voting this answer as, although I largely agree with your points, this is not the forum for a rant. Less rant, more answer please.

Comment: @vascowhite: just lol, where do you see raging talk? If you haven't noticed I have given 6, yes 6, ways/answers to solve his problem. And **ALL** of this methods are way better that the answer which has +1 ;) If this is raging, then what is this > http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67332 ???

Comment: You can't use this before 5.2.

Comment: @zzatkin: no, DateTime::createFromFormat cannot be used before < 5.3.0; that's why they are 5 different solutions at the end of the answer, that will work even on 4.x.

Comment: @Glavić : thanks for the answer how do i change this unix timestamp to  same date which i gave as input

Comment: @hitesh: just use '->format()' method on DateTime object

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $dateString));
```

Or better yet, convert the string into `YYYY-MM-DD` before you insert.

Comment: because I'm new to php and I didn't know that function :) thanks

Comment: Why why why why why explode or replace string??? Just use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

If you receive from a form the date in format "dd/mm/yyyy" and you need to convert it in "yyyy-mm-dd" you can simply use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$date_eng=substr($data_ita,6,4)."-".substr($data_ita,3,2)."-".substr($data_ita,0,2);
```

and

```
$data_ita=substr($date_eng,8,2)."/".substr($date_eng,5,2)."/".substr($date_eng,0,4);
```

Comment: it looks to me that with strtotime() it works also in dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: Yes, strtotime() seems to work also with "dd-mm-yyyy". I thought your question was also related to switching between european and us format.

Comment: @gabs: strtotime() _seems_ to work also with "dd-mm-yyyy", but be aware that "each parameter of this function [strtotime] uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter" (from [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)). Changing timezone of the server can lead you to unexpected behaviours. Perhaps it's better use a DateTime object as suggested by mark-baker.

Comment: Why why why why why explode, replace or even cut string??? Just use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: @Glavić: as said, it's better use a DateTime object

Comment: But why do you teach newbies "old" (if I can call this old) school?

Comment: Because this way is always available, even with version of PHP older than 5.3 (and yes, there are a lot of not updated servers in the world, and sometimes you must use _ancient_ technology), and not last because if a newbie understands how to perform an operation with simple statements, then it can use more complex objects with a deeper comprehension. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: Are you sure that this is always available? What if OP has php v1-v3? So what if they are servers with old php? Will we write php v4 code when php v26.4.x will be out? And using 4 years old code is not latest for me.

Answer (score 0):

Quite lengthy.

```
$get_array = explode('/', 'dd/mm/yyyy');

$day = $get_array[0];
$month = $get_array[1];
$year = $get_array[2];
$time_Stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
```

Comment: Why why why why why explode or replace string??? Just use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: @Glavić Because its not supported below PHP 5.3

Comment: There is 5.5 already out. I think answers should be for the latest code, not for code from year 2006; [yes php5.2 was released in 2006 and 5.3 in 2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). If OP needs old code example, he needs to tell that.

Comment: @Glavić you're right and I +1 your answer because of that, but let others answer without the repetitive criticism huh? That's why you appear to be ranting a little. As always in php, there is more than just one right answer and more than one functional perspective. Respect others. :)