# Converting string to time in PHP

Tags: php, string, timestamp, strtotime

I am having some trouble trying to convert string to time.

My Code is:

```
$time = strtotime("14 November, 2013 2:30 AM");
echo $time ."<br />";
echo date("m/d/Y", $time);
```

I know that [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is not magic, and I checked out the [acceptable date/time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) but I am not sure how to convert the string to another string without converting it to time first.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Write your own function.

Comment: I plan to, just as soon as someone answers my question.

Comment: Use regular expressions to rewrite your input date string into an acceptable date/time format before using `strtotime`.

Comment: what you're doing is the reliable, correct way. to skip the convert-to-UTC step would require doing string manipulation, which will break eventually under some circumstance.

Comment: Is regex really the only way?

Comment: @Kristian Can you elaborate just a little. What do you mean by `the convert to UTC step`?

Comment: `strtotime` returns a UTC. UTC is an integer which is the base unit for most other time functions in PHP. so, typically you want to start with a UTC when doing formatting. in your first step, you get the UTC. then your next step is that you reformat that UTC into a different string format. It is my opinion that in PHP this is the reliable way to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to rewrite the string using [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`list`](http://php.net/list).

```
<?php
// here we assume "day month, year time AMPM"
$date = "14 November, 2013 2:30 AM";

// assign a variable to each part of the string
list($day,$month,$year,$time,$ampm) = explode(" ",$date);

// remove the commas at the end of the month
$month = str_replace(',','',$month);

// Now we rewrite the strtotime string
$time = strtotime($month . " " . $day . ", " . $year . " " . $time . " " . $ampm);

echo $time ."<br />";
echo date("m/d/Y", $time);
```

Comment: missing a param in str_replace, but other than that this worked great for me since I am using an older version of PHP.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at DateTime::createFromFormat and then call format on the created DateTime instance.

Something like:

```
$yourTimeString = '14 November, 2013 2:30 AM';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, Y h:i A', $yourTimeString);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: +1, this should be accepted answer, not bunch of `list`, `explode`, `str_replace` etc. functions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18762582/67332

Answer (score 0):

Php `date()` function allow natural language string for parsing date,

```
for Ex:

echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime("first monday of 2019-07")); // returns first monday of july 2019

echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime("last sat of July 2008"));
```

You can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) php instructions to parsing date as natural languages.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php